# Pickling exposed classes when there are multiple Boost.Python Modules 

Tags: python, boost-python, pickle

I achieved to expose some C++ classes to python with the help of boost. I defined two distinct modules linked statically to my application. I can use the classes defined in those module, derived them, etc.

```c++
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module1)
{
  class_<MyClass, boost::noncopyable>("MyClass", no_init)
    .enable_pickling();
}
```

However, i can't pickle them because of an error not related to pickle. The __ module __ attribute is incorrect for my classes. Thus, pickle fail to get the class back. If my two python modules are "module1" and "module2", and module1 defines a class names MyClass, the following code :

```py
print(module1.MyClass.__name__)
print(module1.MyClass.__module__)

pickle.dumps(module1.MyClass,0)
```

will output

```
MyClass
module2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(module1.MyClass,0)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module2.MyClass'>: attribute lookup
module2.MyClass failed
```

It proves that the __ module __ attribute isn't filled properly for this class. I can't find a workarround. I didn't find any people having a similar problem.

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Comment: I don't think your problems are related to it being a C class. This looks like an error related to there being multiple Modules. Am I correct in my assumption that this is an Embedding situation? Since both modules are statically linked? Is BP is self Statically linked?

Comment: Yes you are correct. That is an embedding situation, i should have mentionned that. boost::python is not itself statically linked. After searching a bit more about this problem, i found a discussion about the exact same problem :
http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/255760
It seems that the problem come from boost:python, that it is old (10 years old) and is not likely to be solved.
I found a workarround : i manually set the __ module __ field in the module initialisation.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. If you add it as a answer to this question, then other people can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [other discussions](http://gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/255760), there is currently no ideal solution to this problem. However, there is a way to "manually" solve the problem by setting __ module __ field in the module initialisation.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module1)
{
  class_<MyClass, boost::noncopyable> myClass("MyClass", no_init)
    .enable_pickling();

  myClass.attr("__module__") = "module1";
}
```

This way, pickle won't fail to identify the module where the class is defined.